# Shortest paths algorithm that preserves direct connections?

Tags: algorithm, scipy, dijkstra

I would like to estimate the distance between vertices in a graph that are not directly connected.

Is there an algorithm that works like Dijkstra's with the exception that existing direct connections are preserved?

Assume the following example:

```
   (A)
 1/   \
(B)    |
1|     |5
(C)    |
 1\   /
   (D)
```

Dijkstra's algorithm would set the distance between nodes (A) and (D) to be 3, whereas I'd like the existing direct connection to be be respected and the distance to be 5. I've tried to use unweighted distances in scipy's implementation without any luck. The problem is that paths with fewer jumps but longer total distance is chosen over paths with shorter distances and more jumps:

```
   (A)
 1/   \5
(B)    |
1|    (E)
(C)    |
 1\   /5
   (D)
```

In this case I'd like the (A) -> (B) -> (C) -> (D) to be used, but unweighted Dijkstra prefers (A) -> (E) -> (D).

Comment: Huh? I don't understand what you are asking. Do you want the shorter path or not? In your first example you seemingly don't want it, and with the second example you do. Make up your mind.

Comment: " but unweighted Dijkstra prefers (A) -> (E) -> (D)." How so? that path has length 10, the other length 3.

Comment: @Tim this is a legitimate request.  For example, you might want to drive from one place to another, but avoid traffic lights.  Let's say that each node represents a set of traffic lights.  You may prefer to drive further and avoid delays.

Comment: @paddy What you say might be true, but he isn't explaining it in a coherent manner. The way it is formulated is a mess that doesn't make any sense. He doesn't say explicitly that he wants what you explain in your answer. I don't know how you were able to read that from the question

Comment: @Tim The second example, if you'll notice, has an extra node in it.  The OP is saying in the first example that 1 hop with a distance of 5 is better than 3 hops with a distance of 3.  In the second example, they prefer 3 hops with a distance of 3 over 2 hops with a distance of 10.  Try running my suggested cost function over these two examples.

Comment: @paddy I understand your interpreteation of his question perfectly fine. And it may well be what he intended. I am only saying, regardless of whether it is what he actually intended or not, his question doesn't ask what you are answering because the question itself is muddled to the point of incoherency.

Comment: @Tim Maybe your initial reaction is clouding your judgement =)  Or maybe I've spent a lot of time tutoring people in my past, and I find it easier to read between the lines.  Some terminology in the question is a little muddled, but I think it's quite clear what they are asking.

Comment: @paddy Ok, I am glad you think so. Given your answer, It seems to fit well with the OP's expectations. My negative opinion of the question stands though.

Comment: @Tim, sorry for being unclear. What I'm trying to do is filling missing values in a sparse connectivity matrix. I know for a fact that the distance between (A) and (D) is 5 in the first example but have no  direct measurement of the distance between (A) and (D) in the second.

Comment: Hmm, the above comment seems to add confusion, not clear it up.

Comment: @Tim, I use term "unweighted" as in scipy's implementation: "Find unweighted distances. That is, rather than finding the path between each point such that the sum of weights is minimized, find the path such that the number of edges is minimized."

Comment: @paddy, I agree I sound confusing. The reason for this is partly the problem I try to solve. My nodes aren't actually nodes but grid cells in an ocean model and I'm not interested in distances but time. I let virtual particles follow simulated ocean currents to estimate the shortest travel time between different parts of the ocean. My problem is that I can only follow a limited number of particles and run the simulation for a limited time. Most grid cells aren't connected and I use Dijkstra to fill the gaps, but the resulting times are much shorter that actually measured by particles.

Comment: Sometimes when you simplify a problem down to ask a question, you end up asking the wrong thing.  I suggest you post another question with more details about what you are doing, why the problem exists, and how you have tried to solve the problem.  You might find that someone comes along and tells you that you're using the wrong algorithm.

Comment: @brorfred Ok, that meaning for unweighted is much clearer for me then. I thought for some reason you were talking about weighting the cost function like in paddy's answer. I think paddy is right that you might get better results by asking specifically about your actual problem. As for the Dijkstra direction, I think the answer you got is the best you can really do.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that what you're trying to do is estimate the distance between places that are not already directly connected. For the places that are already connected, use the given distance?

Comment: That's exactly the case!

Comment: OK, then I wrote down an answer that solves this problem for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Dijkstra.  You just need to modify the cost function.  Instead of single distance or hop measures, you define your own that combines them.

When you choose a node as the best path candidate so far, you can store the number of hops taken to reach it.  That's easy, because you know how many hops were stored on the node you arrived from.

The cost function is then up to you.  You might want each hop to incur a penalty of 2.  So you would then say the cost of reaching node `Q` from node `P` is:

```
Cost(P,Q) = (Hops(P)+1) * 2 + Dist(P,Q)
```

As Tim pointed out in the comments, this is actually equivalent to adding 2 to all your path weights, without requiring any additional coding.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish the same thing without modifying the cost function. You can add the constant penalty directly to the path weights. Probably less programming required.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for making a good point.  Given that I've supplied a linear cost function, simply adding two to all the path weights would be sufficient.  If the cost function was non-linear, then a specialised cost function would be necessary.

Comment: The hop penalty seems like it would have to be at least 2 like you have chosen if the OP would like to rule out the many hop path for the first case. Or do you see it differently?

Comment: That's correct.  As they stated in their question, they want to select A-D in Example 1, and A-B-C-D in Example 2.

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding correctly that what you're trying to do is estimate the distance between places that are not already directly connected. For the places that are already connected, use the given distance?

If so, you can use unmodified Dijkstra for this purpose. Dijkstra takes as input a choice of source node s and the matrix D where D[i,j] is the distance from i to j, and as output it gives you the array Ps where Ps[i] is the length of the shortest path from node s to node i. From Ps and D, there is a way to get the actual shortest path.

Now, what you're trying to do is to fill in entries of D with an estimate for the distance. A reasonable estimate for D[i,j] would be the length of the shortest path from i to j (going through the existing edges).

So what I suggest is the following algorithm:

```
foreach node i:
  if D[i,j] is filled in for all j, move on to the next i
  run Dijkstra from i, resulting in the array Pi.
  for every j s.t. D[i,j] is not yet filled, set D[i,j] := Pi[j]
```

There you go! For your first example this will set d[A,D]=5 (as you expect),
and for the second example it will correctly set d[A,D]=3.